# UICollectionView cells not displaying properly when in parent view controller

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiinterfaceorientation, uicollectionviewlayout

In an app for iPad, I have a view controller 'A' with a collectionview that displays differently based on the orientation, i.e. vertically scrolling in landscape & horizontally scrolling in portrait. I have 2 separate uicollectionviewlayouts to achieve this, with different cells registered and everything, which I set when device orientation changes.
The problem is when I push a view controller 'B' in response to clicking the collectionview cells in 'A', say in portrait mode & I now switch the device to landscape mode (while in 'B'). Now on clicking back from 'B' to 'A', the layout of the collectionview has changed to horizontally scrolling, however the visible cells displaying are out of place :( Manually scrolling the collectionview or manually changing orientations (rotate device to portrait & then again to landscape) when back to view 'A' is the only way which makes the cells display properly. I've done everything from invalidating the layouts and setting it on orientation change for view 'B' in view 'A' and even tried all the reloading stuff such as

```
[self.collectionView reloadData]; as well as
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
```

However, neither of these work. I'm assuming its because the view 'A' is not visible when view controller 'B' is pushed onto 'A' is causing the issue. I'd like some guidance how to fix this problem as I'm at my wits end.